# Azure Kubernetes : Spring Batch running on Ubuntu 18.04 is getting killed rarely

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes, spring-batch, azure-aks

I have a Spring batch 2.1.x application deployed on Azure Kubernetes. Base image is Ubuntu 18.04. I see that the process is getting killed at times.

**Process flow:**

1. kubectl command line command to start the bash script
2. bash script to start the spring batch
3. spring batch application to print / generate the CSV file

[image]

Comment: Consider adding some information about the script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly normal in a Kubernetes environment that pods are shutdown sometimes and that replacement pods are scheduled on another worker node. This happens all the time due to node maintenance or to balance the workload. You can read more about this in the [documentation about pod-lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/).

Comment: Does it mean that the running process(tag print) is killed due to the kubernetes internal maintenance?

Comment: Yes this is my theory, you should be able to confirm it by looking at the event history for the pod or deployment.